# How does stroking metal with a magnet magnetize the metal?

Tags: electromagnetism

How does stroking metal with a magnet magnetize the metal? I have thought about it for a while and got absolutely no clue as to how the magnetic domains in the steel rod got shifted to the same direction (regions of metallic ions pointing the same direction, in an unmagnetised metal these domains cancel each other).

related [link showing the stroking of metal with a magnet](https://www.google.com/search?q=magnet%20stroking%20method&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01ky6dQ_H8t39fNrQzb9M6jknJqMQ%3A1624351332993&ei=ZKLRYJ7-O8eYafzLuKgN&oq=stroking%20magn&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIABCHAhAUUKLtAVim-AFg6IoCaANwAngAgAGsAogBiQmSAQUyLTQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz#kpvalbx=_iKLRYNPEIdKKaqWzqvgI66). Its particularly the manner in which we are stroking that could be causing the magnetisation. The video shows it being repeatedly stroked the same direction

Comment: The phenomenon is called ferromagnetism, you can look it up. I can not check the video, but if we are talking about the same thing, the "stroking" matters not.

Comment: @BarbaudJulien if i am right dont you need a strong electric field for ferrromagnetism to be seen? here they were using just a bar magnet

Comment: I humbly admit that I don't know the order of magnitude of the field necessary to magnetize a piece of iron. But I would consider their experiment a proof that the magnet is enough ;) maybe someone more used to the practical aspect of this stuff can come and confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a ferromagnetic material is placed in, and then removed from, a magnetic field, the “remnant” magnetization within the material will depend on the strength of the field.  Stroking a bar will bring the strong field from the pole of the magnet into close proximity with each part of the bar.  Then the magnetic “domains” within the bar tend to drop back into alignment with nearest crystal axis.